# How to fixate RJ-45 double coupling

Tags: ethernet, design, socket

I have the following RJ-45 network double coupling:

[image]

I have a 3d printer and am trying to print an enclosure or "mount" where I can put that in so that it is properly fixated and I can plug and unplug cables without issues. However I do have some troubles coming up with a design that would work for that.

Does anyone see what the designers had in mind for where to "put" that adapter into? All the ideas that I had essentially only make it fixed in one direction but it can still move into the other direction...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a look at what is called a Keystone Wall Plate. These have rectangular holes that compatible RJ-45 jacks and adapters can slide in and snap into place. The picture of your adapter looks like it is a compatible type. Here is what one of these looks like (front and back):

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TY3MW5Q)*</sup>

You could take careful measurements off one of these wall plates and come up with a suitable 3D model for the hole and retainer edges that you could factor into your 3D printer model.

Alternatively, once you do some research on various types of products that incorporate Keystone modular mount holes, you may decide to purchase some ready made item. Such item could be used as intended or you could take a DIY approach and modify the item to fit your application. Check out the following link for an example 3D printer project.

https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4302166

[image]

<sup>*[Picture Source](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4302166)*</sup>

Comment: That is much simpler than what I had already thought of, and I also found some STLs to try from.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different solution is to take a two-jack faceplate and 2 jacks and wire them together and mount in a plastic box. The plastic boxes are really inexpensive - a quick search finds them for 32 cents apiece (including two nails that you'll remove, assuming you want this gadget to be portable and not fixed in place).

Of course, that avoids the fun part of 3-D printing. But if you have other more interesting things to 3-D print then that shouldn't be a problem.